# Proposal: Remove the "international-travel" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, proposals

I assume everything on the site is international. International for me means travelling abroad, but abroad is always different depending on the home country, so I have no idea what is the purpose of the tag.

Comment: I would Concur...

Comment: I agree, it's too broad to be useful.  If appropriately tagged, I'd guess 80%+ of questions would have this tag.

Answer (score 14):

Right now, this tag is applied on:

1. What are the best things to see in Copenhagen, Denmark?
2. What are some of the sights to see in Budapest, Hungary?
3. Being safe in an unknown place [closed]
4. Online resources/communities especially for travelling to remote islands

1,2,4 are NOT international, they are about one city or one island.
The third was closed.

Conclusion: this tag is already being misused.
Either we do something to make it more understandable, or we remove it.

Also, I am worried 50% of the questions might actually fit for the tag, is that a non-problem? Maybe it is a tip that we should create finer-grained tags?

Comment: I agree with you about the first two and removed the tags.

Comment: I don't understand how the first two questions are not international but the fourth is?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: You are right, fixed.

Answer (score 8):

The [international-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-travel) tag seems reasonable for questions dealing with traveling *between* nations; but not for specific destination questions (everywhere is international to *someone*).

The tag has been removed from inappropriate questions, but this tag is in need of a [Tag Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/). The first two pages of tags [**should have excellent tag wiki excerpts**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), at a minimum.

Comment: Makes sense. I just suspect there's going to be a lot of moderation going on, just because people won't read the tag wiki. Anyway... good to see other opinions on this.

Comment: @Slavo: When enough of the community is aware of the proper behavior (i.e. the use case for *that* tag), community self-moderation can/should start kicking in. Community self-moderation: Most people will emulate the behaviors they see on the site.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree. There are already [lots](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-easiest-transportation-to-use-throughout-romania-for-a-foreigner) [of](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116/how-much-russian-do-i-need-to-know-for-travelling-within-russia) [questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/189/public-transport-in-the-usa) that cover travel not *between* nations (that's what I would translate international-travel to), but *inside* them, so international-travel might be an adequate differentiator.

Comment: Why wouldn't the traveling-abroad tag not accomplish this then?

Comment: @Chris we might have synonyms on our hands.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, such tag has very strange meaning. Yes, there're questions in group "international travel" and outside it. But since the tag is so broad, you will never be able to catch all the appropriate questions. And as well, I don't think that the tag helps anybody in searching for a question (which is the most important meaning of a tag -- to ease the search).